# Load more not working

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery

Load more PRODUCT not working

**js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.ias({
        container : ".category-products",
        item : "ul.products-grid",
        next : "a.next",
        pagination : '.pages',
        loader : "<img src='/skin/frontend/default/default/images/opc-ajax-loader.gif' />",
        triggerPageThreshold : 9999
    });
});

</script>
```

**XML**

```
 <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery-ias.min.js</name></action>

                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/jquery.ias.css</stylesheet></action>
```

**BROWSER CONSOLVE ERROR**

```
TypeError: jQuery.ias is not a function


jQuery.ias({
```

I followed this `

> http://astrio.net/blog/loading-products-with-ajax/

`

Comment: In which file you have added xml code and post your xml code?

Comment: please check that jquery-ias.min.js call  before  jqury

Comment: @PrashantValanda i added pge.xml

Comment: @AmitBera sorry i am not getting

Comment: Post added xml code of page.xml in your question.

Comment: <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery-ias.min.js</name></action>

                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/jquery.ias.css</stylesheet></action>

Comment: page.xml code need to see jquery sequence and have you added code between <default></default>

Comment: yes i added in between default only

Comment: Please  check page source of your page  and check that   jquery-ias.min.js call load jquery.js?

Comment: Ya i alredy checked it calling properley